# is there a way to convert partial bangla font from json out put?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

i am using a 3rd party geocoder, where response comes partially English and partially bangla,
so when i am printing the out put, i get unreadable output.

i want to convert the out put so that i can see the expected result (english and bangla)

my code : -

```
[import requests

class geocoder():


    def __init__(self, lat, lon):
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
        print(self.lat)
        print(self.lon)

    @property
    def nominatim(self):
        nominatim_url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=geojson&lat=23.798267&lon=90.384427"
        nominatim_result  = requests.get(url=nominatim_url)
        nominatim_json = nominatim_result.json()
        print (nominatim_json\['features'\]\[0\]\['properties'\]\['display_name'\])


result = geocoder(23.798267, 90.384427)

print(result.nominatim)
```

Please find the correct screen shot from postman

[postman out put , where english and bangal fonts are good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fpuT.png)

[Python out put english wording is fine but bangla not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H8rJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your editor/IDE.  An IDE that supports an appropriate font and an encoding such as UTF-8 works fine.  Here's the output of your example using the PythonWin IDE from the `pywin32` module on Windows 10:

```
23.798267
90.384427
Building No:21(kha), B-21(kha), Mirpur road-14, উত্তর কাফরুল, পূর্ব কাজীপাড়া, ঢাকা, ঢাকা জেলা, ঢাকা বিভাগ, 1206, Bangladesh
None
```